# Regex to match to urls

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex

i'm looking for a regex to match between the 2 following url's:

```
1) https://www.youtube.com/
2) https://www.youtu.be/
```

and of course with queries.

```
1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqw4w9wgxcq&feature=youtu.be
2) http://youtu.be/dqw4w9wgxcq
```

and i want to check it after form submit.

the regex i have now is:

```
 var expression = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  var regex = new RegExp(expression);

  if (!linkVal.match(regex)) {
    alert("PLease enter a valid url");
    return;
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need a little more info. *Only* these two URLs? Is it capturing paths no matter how long or nested the folder paths are? Are they assumed safe URLs?

Comment: @JoelHager no, all the pathes that comes after youtube.com or youtu.be . i assume that all youtube links are safe.

Comment: So it's *all* youtube links?

Comment: @JoelHager Prefer all video links.

Comment: I'll clarify - What are you ending up doing with the captured data? There are *tons* of checks you'd have to do if it's nebulous (i.e. check for https or relative path etc.)

Comment: @JoelHager I'm downloading the videos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214127/discussion-between-joel-hager-and-mendi-sterenfeld).

Comment: Can you provide an example of *how* the app is seeing the content? That way I can make sure my regex solution will actually satisfy your use-case. (Answering questions when the question isn't super clear is what gets the answerer down-voted).

Comment: @JoelHager check out at ytgenz herokuapp.com

Comment: The closest I got is `/[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?]{2,256}youtu.*\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)` - It just will capture *anything* that starts with youtu (but there may be a website that does as well. I'm trying to bone up on lookbehind capture for regex to help you out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?]{2,256}(youtube.[a-z]{2,6}|youtu.be)\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)`

There might be a couple circumstances that would fail this, but This is fairly robust in my testing. Let me know if any URLs fail and I can take a look. :)

```js
const regex = /[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?]{2,256}(youtube.[a-z]{2,6}|youtu.be)\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/;
const entries = [
'https://youtube.com',
'www.fakename.com',
'www.youtu.be/pathtoname',
'https://youtu.be/',
'http://youtabe.com/',
'https://youtube.com',
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuXWTnzacyQ',
'https://youtucan.com',
'https://youtunow.com'
];


const validUrls = entries.filter( e => e.match(regex) );
console.log(validUrls);
```

If you provide a sample list of youtube URLs, I can show that it works. I just don't have an API to grab a JSON of 100 or so videos to check.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a regex for that. Use the native `URL` object to parse the URLs and implement your logic on top of that.

```js
const urls = [
    'http://youtube.com/',
    'https://www.youtu.be',
    'http://www.youtu.b',
    'invalid'
];

console.log(urls.map(url => [url, isValidUrl(url)]));

function isValidUrl(urlString) {
    let url;

    try { url = new URL(urlString) } 
    catch { return false }

    return isValidProtocol() && isValidDomain();

    function isValidProtocol() {
        return url.protocol === 'http:' || url.protocol === 'https:';
    }

    function isValidDomain() {
        const coreDomain = url.hostname.replace(/^www\./, '');

        return coreDomain === 'youtube.com' || coreDomain === 'youtu.be';
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to specify *every* TLD? .co.jp/.de/.co.uk/etc.?

Comment: @JoelHager Well, the OP only specified these 2, but he could always use a regex from this point (or enumerate them all) now that the URL is properly parsed. The point is to avoid making the core parsing with regexes.

Comment: Per his comments and link, the urls are user inputted one at a time as text.

Comment: @JoelHager Oh ok, well I haven't read all communications and from the question only it's not very clear what he was trying to achieve. From the gist of the code he posted he seemed to be looking at validating URLs and using a URL parser is the more robust & simple way to go here IMO, even if you use regexes for further simple validations.